# Sending to the printer the content of an url

Tags: javascript, html, printing, hyperlink

I know that I can print the current page by calling

```
javascript:windows.print()
```

Is it possible to print a page without showing it first? I mean if I have a link I would like to send to the printer the content of the target_url.

```
<a href="target_url">Click to print the target_url</a>
```

I can load it with ajax, but there's anyway to send this content to the printer?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about using an iframe? Load the contents in an iframe that is not visible and then print the iframe.

Answer (score 1):

You could load your content into a hidden frame and then have it call `window.print()`. That will result in the browser's native "Print" dialog being shown to the user. You cannot force the client machine to start printing something without user approval.

Comment: I haven't asked for avoiding user approval, I want it to be shown.

Comment: Oh well that's OK then.  A lot of people ask how to do that on Stackoverflow :-)